# Insert record if not exists in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

May be this question was asked many times, but not working in my case.

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks_taskstatus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `video_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `creative_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `missing_asset` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_finished` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `share_with_am` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ordering` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `ready_to_begin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `in_progress` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_conformed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `order_item_equivalent` varchar(60) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=122 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to insert a record in mysql database if it was not already exists, below is the query i was trying to use.

```
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `tasks_taskstatus` 
SET `name`='Saveout - In Progress', 
`video_status`=1, 
`creative_status`=0, 
`missing_asset`=0, 
`is_finished`=0, 
`share_with_am`=0, 
`ordering`=4, 
`ready_to_begin`=0, 
`in_progress`=1, 
`is_conformed`=0, 
`order_item_equivalent`='';
```

But everytime i run this query a new record was being created, so what's wrong in the above statement and how can i modify the above query in order to insert the data/record only if not exists?

Comment: Show your table schema.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Tried all the ways mentioned in your comment link, but was not working

Comment: If you look through your records, how are they different on each new insert?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Above is the table schema

Comment: @BrettDeWoody OK they should be different on name and video_status fields

Answer (score 0):

You don't `INSERT` an `id` (which is your primary key), so the `AUTO_INCREMENT` kicks in and generates a new id and inserts a new record.

Ask yourself: how would MySQL know *which* record to update? If you know that (an example answer could be "by the `name`"), then you can change your keys and this should work.

If the combination of `name` and `video_status` has to be unique, create an extra key:

```
ALTER TABLE `tasks_taskstatus` ADD UNIQUE(`name`, `video_status`);
```

Comment: ok the records should be differentiated based on name and video_status fields

Comment: how about this ?   `INSERT INTO `tasks_taskstatus` (`name`, `video_status`, `creative_status`, `missing_asset`, `is_finished`, `share_with_am`, `ordering`, `ready_to_begin`, `in_progress`, `is_conformed`, `order_item_equivalent`) VALUES ('Saveout - In Progress', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0,'') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from `tasks_taskstatus` WHERE `name`='Saveout - In Progress' AND `video_status`=1);`

Comment: @shivakrishna that would insert a new record. `INSERT IGNORE` and `REPLACE` work, if there would be a key violation otherwise. Change your table schema to add a `UNIQUE` key to `name` and `video_status`.